# modify parameter without reference

Tags: c++

I'm using an external library, and I have a class inheriting from another class with the next function

**void IOCallback::Open(const char* filename, bool isOpen)**

I need to modify the bool and I can't modify the code to use it like reference.

is there anyway I can achieve this?

Comment: You can modify the local copy your method receives, but there's no mechanism that will allow you to modify the caller's copy AFAIK.

Comment: What code can't you modify? You'd obviously have to modify the callers to do something with the returned bool and you'd obviously have to modify the function to return a bool. Is it just the function argument types that you can't modify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to modify the bool and I can't modify the code to use it like reference.

If you mean like this...

```
bool b = false;
IOCallback callback;
callback.Open(filepath, b);
if(b) {  // <- will never actually evaluate to anything but false
    // do something
}
```

...then, well, you can't.  The function receives a copy of its argument.  You are free to modify the argument from within the function, but you will not be able to do so in such a way that the caller would be able to see said modification.

I question the reasoning behind this request.  If you wrote the code then you can modify it or add another overloaded version to do what you need.  If you did not write the code and cannot modify it then it was never intended to mutate its argument in the first place, so what's to be gained?

Comment: thanks guys for pointing me in the correct direction, that function was intended to be used for debug purposes when a file is open and not for real i/o

Comment: my intention was to use it for example: if the file is present on disk then read it normally, if not then with the callback try to read it from another source, i.e. file inside zip file.